# Azure Data Explorer Ingestion, DeleteSourceOnSuccess does not work

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am ingesting a zip file from blob storage to ADX and set the option DeleteSourceOnSuccess = true.
The ingestion works fine but unfortunately, the source file is not deleted after the operation.
How can I debug this?

```
var kustoIngestionProperties = new KustoIngestionProperties(databaseName: adxDatabase, tableName: table);
kustoIngestionProperties.AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
      {"zipPattern", "stats*.txt"},
      {"format", "json"},
      {"ingestionMappingReference", "WiFiJsonMapping"}
};
var sourceOptions = new StorageSourceOptions() { DeleteSourceOnSuccess = true };

IRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new NoRetry();
((IKustoQueuedIngestClient)client).QueueRetryPolicy = retryPolicy;
try
{     
     var sourceBlobSAS = CreateBlobUriWithSas(source_blob);
     await client.IngestFromStorageAsync(uri: sourceBlobSAS, ingestionProperties: kustoIngestionProperties, sourceOptions);
     log.LogInformation($"File: {source_blob.Name} ingested to {tenant}_{site}_raw_logs");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex.ToString());
    throw;
}
finally
{
    client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What SDK version were you using? 
Did you provide the SourceBlobSas the permission to delete the blob?